# How to calculate the position of A, B on a circle?

Tags: geometry

> How to calculate the position of $A$ and $B$ on the circle?
>
> I know
>
> $$OD = OE = \text{radius} = 10$$
> $$OF` = OG = CF = CG = 4$$

[image]

(Reposted from [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67145515/how-to-calculate-the-position-of-a-b-on-a-circle?).)

Comment: Use Pythagoras equation with 4 and 10.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use the equation of the circle $x^2+y^2=100$ and intersect with $x=4$ and $y=4$, and then solve for solutions in first quadrant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can try and help with $B$ and you can work similarly on $A$. We already know the $y$-coordinate of $B$ is $4$ and we already know the $x$-coordinate of $A$ is $4$. We can use right triangles for the other coordinate.

1. Draw the line segment $OB$.
2. Draw a line vertically down from $B$ (parallel to $y$-axis) to the $x$-axis.
3. We have created a right triangle. We know the hypotenuse (which is the radius) is 10 and we know the height of the triangle is 4 (from the square).
4. Let $\theta$ be the angle of incline of the hypotenuse from the $x$-axis. Then,
   $$ \sin(\theta) = \frac{4}{10} $$
5. Now that we know the angle $\theta = \arcsin(0.4)$, we know $$B = (10\cos(\theta), 10\sin(\theta)) = (10\cos(\arcsin(0.4)), 4).$$

For $A$ it should be similar.